# Different minimum and maximum for integer and number in json schema

Tags: jsonschema

Let's say I have schema where a property can be either an integer or a number. Is there a way to specify a different maximum depending on the type of value? For example:

```
{
  "type": ["integer", "number"],
  "max-if-integer": 255,
  "max-if-number": 1.0
}
```

couldn't find anything about it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are on draft7 or later, if/then/else is probably the best way to express this. if it's earlier, you can get there with `oneOf`, as discussed on gregsdennis's answer.

```json
{
  "if": {"type": "integer"},
  "then": {
    "minimum": integer-minimum,
    "maximum": integer-maximum
  },
  "else": {
    "type": "number",
    "minimum": float-minimum,
    "maximum": float-maximum
  }
}
```

do note however that `1.0` and `1` are both considered integers according to the json schema spec, and will use the integer `then`, not the number `else` like non-whole-number floats.

Answer (score 1):

`oneOf` is going to be your friend!

```
{
  "oneOf": [
    { "type": "integer", "maximum": 255 },
    { "type": "number", "maximum": 1 }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this will fail on any non-integer number in the range of both schemas' minimum and maximum, since both oneOfs will pass when only one is allowed to. you could get there with a `not: {type: integer}` alongside the `type: number`.

Comment: Remember, integers are also numbers. if those maximums were reversed, things wouldn't work out so well.